# No output with Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following piece of code:

```
Assuming[{\[Rho] > 0, z > 0, m > 0, \[CapitalOmega] > 0}, Simplify[expr, TimeConstraint -> 1000]] // Timing
```

where
`expr` is some big expression:

```
expr = Uncompress["1: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"]
```

When I start evaluations Mathematica gives nothing as an output. It just stops (at around 100s with `TimeConstraint = 1000` and at around 90s with `TimeConstraint = Infinity`). If I run it with `TimeConstraint = 10` it doesn't stop at all working for about 15 mins (though giving several expected warnings `Simplify::time: Time spent on a transformation exceeded 10. seconds`).

I cannot see any reason why it shall behave like that, giving no output at all. My version is Mathematica 10.2. Will be grateful for any explanation.

EDIT: The problem resolved with upgrading to Mathematica 11.2

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, was not aware of that :) Thanks for editing the question